# Python cant call a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I am developing a rock paper scissors on python and I am stuck.
I made a class that cycles between (rock, paper, and scissors ), I want the computer to know it's previous play.
for instance ( first round computer played rock, in the next round it should play paper)
but I don't know how to call the learn function to make it work

```
class Player:
def __init__(self):
    self.score = 0

def move(self):
    return 'rock'

def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
    self.my_move = my_move
    self.their_move = their_move

def beats(one, two):
return ((one == 'rock' and two == 'scissors') or
        (one == 'scissors' and two == 'paper') or
        (one == 'paper' and two == 'rock'))

class Game:
def __init__(self, p1, p2):
    self.p1 = p1
    self.p2 = p2

def play_round(self):
    move1 = input("Pick something!\n")
    move2 = self.p2.move()
    print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
    self.p1.learn(move1, move2)
    self.p2.learn(move2, move1)
    if beats(move1, move2):
        self.p1.score += 1
        print ("You win")
        print ("Human score = " + str(self.p1.score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(self.p2.score) ) 
    elif beats(move2,move1):
        self.p2.score += 1
        print ("Computer wins")
        print ("Human score = " + str(self.p1.score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(self.p2.score) ) 
    else:
        print ("Draw")
        print ("Human score = " + str(self.p1.score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(self.p2.score) )

def play_game(self):
    print("Game start!")
    for round in range(3):
        print(f"Round {round}:")
        self.play_round()
    print("Game over!")

class human_player(Player):
def move(self):
   return input("Pick something!\n")

class randomplayer(Player):
def move(self):
    return random.choice(moves)

class repeat(Player):
def move(self):
    return 'rock'

class cycleplayer(Player):
def move(self):
    # calling my_move from the Player class
    if self.learn.my_move == "rock" or "paper" or "scissors" :
        return 'rock'

    elif  self.their_move == 'rock':
        return "paper"   

    elif self.their_move == 'paper':
        return "scissors"  

    elif self.their_move == 'scissors':
        return "rock"

if HumanPlayer_choice == "cycle" :
game = Game(Player(), cycleplayer())
game.play_game()
```

This is the error I am getting.

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'function' object has no
>   attribute 'my_move'

I know that I need to utilize the init function with the learn function to make it work but I not sure how.

Comment: Please fix the indentation first, the code you posted is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Fix the indentation please

Comment: Correct indentations of the code otherwise it is just useless.

Comment: On which line does this error occur? Please add the entire traceback

Comment: This is the cause of the `AttributeError`: *`self.learn.my_move`*. `self.learn` is `class method` and you have nowhere a `class method my_move`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems in your code as far as I could follow. Take a look at the example below based on your code. There's some logic I could not follow so it may not behave exactly as you want. Suggestions:

- as you just want to store the previous move for the cycle_player move, store it in the cycle object (instance) not on the Player
- as the move method varies make it's implementation specific to a child class (e.g. human_player, random_player, cycle_player)
- some methods are better as static rather than recreated in each instance methods

  ```
  import random

  class Player:
      def __init__(self):
          self.score = 0

  class Game:
      def __init__(self, p1, p2):
          self.p1 = p1
          self.p2 = p2

      @staticmethod
      def check_result(a, b): #Return win, draw, loose for a over b
          if (a == b):
              return 'draw'
          if (a == 'rock' and b == 'scissors') or (a == 'scissors' and b == 'paper') or (a == 'paper' and b == 'rock'):
              return 'win'
          return 'loose'

      def play_round(self):
          #move1 = input("Pick something!\n")
          move1 = self.p1.move()
          move2 = self.p2.move()
          print(f"Player 1: {move1}  Player 2: {move2}")
          result = Game.check_result(move1, move2) # a over b
          if result == 'win':
              self.p1.score += 1
              print ("You win")
          elif result == 'loose':
              self.p2.score += 1
              print ("Computer wins")
          else:
              print ("Draw")
          print ("Human score = " + str(self.p1.score) + " "  + "Computer score = " + str(self.p2.score))

      def play_game(self):
          print("Game start!")
          for round in range(3):
              print(f"Round {round + 1}:")
              self.play_round()
          print("Game over!")

  class human_player(Player):
      def move(self):
          return input("Pick something!\n") #TODO validate input

  class random_player(Player): #Option in game for computer to make random moves
      def move(self):
          return random.choice(["scissors","paper","rock"])

  class repeat_player(Player): #Option
      def move(self):
          return 'rock'

  class cycle_player(Player):
      def __init__(self):
          self.previous_move = None
          super().__init__()

      def move(self):
          # calling my_move from the Player class
          if self.previous_move is None :
              next_move = 'rock'
          elif  self.previous_move == 'rock':
              next_move = "paper"
          elif self.previous_move == 'paper':
              next_move = "scissors"  
          elif self.previous_move == 'scissors':
              next_move = "rock"
          self.previous_move = next_move
          return next_move

  #game = Game(human_player(), random_player())
  #game = Game(human_player(), repeat_player())
  game = Game(human_player(), cycle_player())
  game.play_game()
  ```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on this line:

```
if self.learn.my_move == "rock" or "paper" or "scissors" :
```

`learn` function does not have an attribute named `my_move`. What you meant to do is probably

```
if self.my_move == "rock" or self.my_move == "paper" or self.my_move == "scissors" :
```

Note that you have to add `self.my_move ==` before `"paper"` and `"scissors"`; otherwise it is evaluated like:

```
if (self.my_move == "rock") or ("paper") or ("scissors"):
```

and since non-empty strings are always evaluated as `True`, this `if` case is rendered useless.

---

As @DmitryErohin mentioned, there is a better way of achieving that without repeating yourself:

```
if (self.my_move in ("rock", "paper", "scissors")):
```

This is much less verbose and a lot more readable

Comment: So no better? `if self.my_move in ("rock", "paper", "scissors"):`

Comment: @DmitryErohin thanks for the feedback. Added that suggestion to the answer too.

Comment: now I am getting this traceback

AttributeError: 'cycleplayer' object has no attribute 'my_move'

Comment: I need to make init function to make use of the learn function, but i am not sure how